# Problem with opening floating window in i3wm: alacritty

Tags: arch, i3, alacritty

I am using i3 in arch and I have switched to alacritty as a terminal.

However, alacritty will not open as a floating window. This is my code in i3 config:

```
bindsym $mod+Return exec alacritty
bindsym $mod+Shift+Return exec -no-startup-id alacritty --role=floating
for_window [window_role="^floating$"] floating enable
```

There is no error message. Interestingly enough: opening a regular window of alacritty and then floating it via $mod+Shift+Space works.

Any hints? Can I somehow troubleshoot this - e.g. execute a window with verbose output as floating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors in your config:

1. Typo in `exec -no-startup-id` missing an extra hyphen(-), should be `exec --no-startup-id`
2. `--role` is not a valid option in alacritty.

Instead you can use `--class` option (to set WM_CLASS property) as below:

```
bindsym $mod+Shift+Return exec --no-startup-id alacritty --class=floating
for_window [class="^floating$"] floating enable
```

Comment: thanks man, that worked. didnt know about the role/class attribute